# How can I use backbone.js to post input values to other areas of a site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, replication

```
<div class="fmMenu accordion">

    <p class="menuItem">Cleaning &amp Specials Inspection
    <input type="checkbox" name="include" value="Cleaning&SpecialsInspectionSelect" class="headerCheckbox"></p>

    <div><h2>
             Notes<br /><textarea name="Clean&SpecialsInspectionNotes" value="" rows="4" cols"50"></textarea></h2>Start date<input type="text" class="datepicker" />       
    </div>




    <p class="menuItem">Porter Service
    <input type="checkbox" name="include" value="PorterServiceSelect" class="headerCheckbox"></p>
    <div><h2>
             Notes<br /><textarea name="PorterServiceNotes" rows="4" cols"50"></textarea></h2>Start date<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
    </div>



    <p class="menuItem">Vacancy Inspection and Cleaning
    <input type="checkbox" name="include" value="VacancyInspectionandCleaningSelect" class="headerCheckbox" id="joyridestop4"></p>
    <div><h2>
             Notes<br /><textarea name="VacancyInspectionandCleaningNotes" rows="4" cols"50"></textarea></h2>Start date<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
    </div>

</div>

<ol>
                            <li style="display:none" class="Cleaning&SpecialsInspectionSelect">Cleaning &amp Specials Inspection</li>
                            <li style="display:none" class"PorterServiceSelect">Porter Service</li>
                            <li style="display:none" class"VacancyInspectionandCleaningSelect">Vacancy Inspection and Cleaning</li>
</ol>



<div class="showHere"><div>
```

**This is my jQuery accordion. I want to use backbone.js to make it so if you click on the "Cleaning&SpecialsInspectionSelect" checkbox and the "VacancyInspectionandCleaningSelect" checkbox and fill in the other inputs for each one's accordion content, they show up in the "showHere" div.**

Here is some code I've tried. It all uses:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checkBoxArray = new Array(
              "Cleaning&SpecialsInspectionSelect",
              "PorterServiceSelect",
              "VacancyInspectionandCleaningSelect",
              );
});
```

Here's some I tried:

```
for(i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length - 1; i++){
    $("input[value=" + checkBoxArray[i] + "]:checked ~ ." + checkBoxArray[i]).css(
    "display", "inherit"
    );
}
```

Here's some more:

```
for(i = 0; i < checkBoxArray.length - 1; i++){
    var overviewElement = $("." + checkBoxArray[i]).hide(),
        ifChecked = $("input[value=checkBoxArray[i]]").click(function(){
            overviewElement.toggle(ifChecked.is(":checked"));
    });
}
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Data. I want to get the input from the text boxes to another part of the site.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to use a global event bus. Make a copy of `Backbone.Events` somewhere that everyone can see it:

```
app.event_bus = _({}).extend(Backbone.Events);
```

Then the view that is the source of the data would trigger an event:

```
app.event_bus.trigger('some_event', data);
```

and the other view would listen for the event:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(app.event_bus, 'some_event', this.some_method);
},
some_method: function(payload) {
    // `payload` will be the `data` from the `trigger` call
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9zD7v/